# wordpress website crash on https

Tags: wordpress, ssl

I have this wordpress website: Hevaweb.ir and I recently bought a ssl certificate. The problem is when the site is on **http** protocol, it works correctly and without any problem, but when I access it via **https**, all of the pictures and menus will crash!!!

I have to refresh the website 3 or 4 times to shows the full contents correctly... (and it will crash again after cleaning the chrome caches and also use ctrl+f5 keys)
I've already tried these methods:

1. I installed the plugins to force Https on every pages (really-simple-ssl, wordpress HTTPS (ssl))
2. I tried to redirect all URLs from https to http manually
3. I checked that if the wordpress url and theme is set on Https in setting section
4. I manually defined Https protocol for my website on wp-config and just in case to .htaccess file
5. I checked the host to see if there is not problem

By the way, cloudflare is not installed either!

Comment: I think, the problem is with your server, not with wordpress. provide full details what server do you use for this website

Comment: I'm using Linux server

Comment: look here( http://www.onlyerrors.com/err_spdy_protocol_error.html ) at `Method 5: Flush DNS and Renew IP`

Comment: and at this one: https://udinra.com/blog/err_spdy_protocol_error-reason-solution . Your problem is getting `ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR` on chrome browsers

Comment: oh my GOD! what is wrong with this damn website ... It's not still loading correctly...I'm losing my mind :-(

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing something, since you're using a theme, try this:

Step 1: Export all your WordPress database with phpMyAdmin for example to a SQL file;

Step 2: Replace all occurrences of http://yourwebsite to **https://yourwebsite** ;

Step 3: Delete the old tables and import the new SQL file with the changes;

Step 4: Check the theme configuration (some themes store their configuration in a file, so sometimes it's hard to find it)

If that doesn't work, try this:

01) Backup your files and database to a .sql file;

02) Delete the WordPress installation;

03) Upload the WordPress files(do not install) and the theme files;

04) Open the .sql file and replace all occurrences of http://yourwebsite to **https://yourwebsite** ;

05) Import the SQL file;

06) Activate the theme;

*Sometimes we need to set all WordPress configuration before activating one theme.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I tried your method too...It didn't work either

Comment: You're welcome. If you say what theme are you using it might help too. :)

Comment: I see that they don't offer a demo download to test the theme, well there is something else that you can try, look this URL: [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) @HengamehVlizadeh